# Pass dict to inheritance after using __new__

Tags: python, inheritance

As part of my script I've done an in depth config class that overrides all the base types to allow for extra control. For example, `config['heading']['value'] = 'xyz'` runs validation before setting the value.

Anyway, I've just spent the last hour tracking down a bug which seemed to happen intermittently, but in actual fact it turns out it's happening all the time and I just never noticed as it's pretty invisible.

This is trimmed down as much as possible while still keeping a general idea of how it works. If I pass in anything and assign it to `cls`, then any new instance of the class will replace the variable. How can I access `cls._data` from `_ConfigItem` without it changing?

```
class _ConfigItem(object):
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

class _ConfigItemStr(str, _ConfigItem):
    def __new__(cls, config_dict):
        cls._data = config_dict
        return str.__new__(cls, cls._data['value'])

s1 = _ConfigItemStr({'value': 'test1'})

print(s1)
#test1
print(s1.data)
#{'value': 'test1'}

s2 = _ConfigItemStr({'value': 'test2'})

print(s1)
#test1
print(s1.data)
#{'value': 'test2'}
```

The wanted result in this case is for `s1.data` to still contain `{'value': 'test1'}`. Side note that this is in Python 2.7 but I plan on having it forwards compatible.

Comment: Why are you assigning things to `cls._data` at all? What was the purpose of that?

Comment: I access the values within `_ConfigItem`, just removed it from this example since it's not important. [Actual file is here](https://github.com/Peter92/MouseTracks/blob/master/core/ini.py) but a bit harder to understand on a quick glance :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `_data` to be a per-instance thing, but for some reason, you're setting it on the class instead. Set it on the instance.

```
class _ConfigItem(object):
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

class _ConfigItemStr(str, _ConfigItem):
    def __new__(cls, config_dict):
        obj = str.__new__(cls, config_dict['value'])
        obj._data = config_dict
        return obj
```

Also, it doesn't look like you need that property. You could just do

```
class _ConfigItemStr(str):
    def __new__(cls, config_dict):
        obj = str.__new__(cls, config_dict['value'])
        obj.data = config_dict
        return obj
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I was thinking something like that but never thought of doing it after calling `type.__new__`. I went as far as trying `copy = cls(cls)` but obviously it didn't work aha.